# How to make the "screen" variable accessible to all scripts in python/pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, python-2.x, pygame-surface

I am making my own UI in python 2 and pygame. I have my main script that creates the "screen" variable for the rendering surface in pygame.

How could I go about letting other python scripts access - and render on - the surface of another script?

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking. Are your scripts related in some ways? Can you explain how you are "calling" them?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I have "extension" scripts that allow people to make their own widgets. These scripts are activated from the main script through a call (ex. ExtensionSample.Main.Draw())

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I would like the extension scripts to be able to render to the screen/surface that the main script already has.

Comment: Note that you can also always use `pygame.display.get_surface()` to get the display surface. (but Mathias Ettinger's answer is a generally better approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by passing your `screen` variable as a parameter on any call of your extensions modules. The easiest way would be to design your modules as classes whose `__init__` method accept the screen to render on:

```
#extension1.py
class Main(whatever_base_class):
    def __init__(self, screen, *args, **kwargs):
        self.screen = screen
        ...
    def Draw(self):
        #use self.screen to draw on screen.
```

And from your main script:

```
from extension1 import Main

#define screen somehow
ext1 = Main(screen, ...)
ext1.Draw()
```

If you can't or don't want to force the creation/modification of an `__init__` in your extensions, you can either rely on a `def setup(screen)` method or directly pass the `screen` variable to the `Draw` method.